# How to calculate AUCs for subsamples in R

Tags: r, prediction, auc

I managed to calculate an overall AUC for my dataset, but now I am interested in calculating and comparing AUCs for subsamples of my dataset. Any idea as to how I can tackle this in R?

Kindly,
IG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very difficult to help you out without some data sample, but lets assume that you have a dataframe of some id, some predictions, and some outcome.

Then you can use dplyr to group data and perform calculations on subsets of the data. I use the package pROC to calculate the auc for the groups.

```
d <- tibble::tibble(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  predicitons = runif(10),
  outcome = factor(c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")))

d %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    auc = as.numeric(pROC::auc(predictor = predicitons, response = outcome)))
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, @Jagge!
I indeed went the way of subsampling and then calculating AUCs with pROC for each small dataset. For some reason I had it in mind that I'd be able to split within the analyses--but that was way beyond my ability :)